# .Net Core File Upload Working on Local but not Working on Live

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a mvc project in .net core.
file uploads are running on local.
but the file upload does not work when I get the project live.
the transaction drops to 404.

thats my code;

```
public IActionResult Add()
{
    var mycategories = ctx.tbCategories.ToList();
    SetUserInfo();
    return View(mycategories);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(Photos photos, IFormFile imagePath, int[] Categories)
{
    string newImageName = photos.name.Replace(' ', '-');
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath.ToString()))
    {
        newImageName = newImageName + Path.GetExtension(imagePath.FileName);
        var uploadFolder = Path.Combine(_HostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot/img/photos");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, newImageName);
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            imagePath.CopyTo(fs);
            fs.Flush();
        }
    }

    photos.createdAt = DateTime.Now;
    photos.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    photos.imagePath = newImageName;

    ctx.tbPhotos.Add(photos);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    int lastIdOfSavedPhoto = ctx.tbPhotos.Max(u => u.Id);
    for (int i = 0; i < Categories.Length; i++)
    {
        PhotoCategories myPhotoCategories = new PhotoCategories();
        myPhotoCategories.photoId = lastIdOfSavedPhoto;
        myPhotoCategories.categoryId = int.Parse(Categories[i].ToString());
        myPhotoCategories.createdAt = DateTime.Now;
        myPhotoCategories.updatedAt = myPhotoCategories.createdAt;
        ctx.tbPhotoCategories.Add(myPhotoCategories);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Photos", "Admin");
}
```

that live server screenshot: [image]

Comment: question seeks debugging. please debug your code and try to be more specific. Only include relevant part of the code

Comment: when i debug it, its working true in local. when i publish on live that add action not working.

Comment: Looks like a routing problem, do other actions work as expected? If other actions work as expected, it could be throwing an error and returning a 404 because it can't find the error page.

Comment: other actions work as normal. just upload action has a error.

Comment: Okay. Do you have some error handling setup so you can see if an exception is being thrown? If you have an exception, add it to your question and then we can help.

Comment: why dont you use remote debugger to debug your testing environment? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Comment: 10:30:28 /Photos/Add
Could not find a part of the path 'test.jpg'.

thats error.

Comment: @onrcn_  From the content of error, the directories that are missing in the `filePath`.